# how to connection error handling in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two server and try to connect either first or second,
If first connection alive than use first connection id else
connect to another server,
But connection id not comes?

## Here is my config/database.php

```
$db['slave01']['hostname'] = 'xx.xx.xxx.xx';
$db['slave01']['username'] = 'xxxxxx';
$db['slave01']['password'] = 'xxxx';
$db['slave01']['database'] = 'xxx';
$db['slave01']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['slave01']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['slave01']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['slave01']['db_debug'] = FALSE;   // =>here set FALSE
$db['slave01']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['slave01']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['slave01']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['slave01']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['slave01']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['slave01']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['slave01']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and another server details

```
    $db['slave02']['hostname'] = 'xx.xx.xxx.xx';
    $db['slave02']['username'] = 'xxxxxx';
    $db['slave02']['password'] = 'xxxx';
    $db['slave02']['database'] = 'xxx';
    $db['slave02']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
    $db['slave02']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['slave02']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['slave02']['db_debug'] = FALSE; // =>here set FALSE
    $db['slave02']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['slave02']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['slave02']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['slave02']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['slave02']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['slave02']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['slave02']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

## in controller

```
    $this->READ = $this->load->database('slave01', TRUE);
    if(!$this->READ->conn_id){
        echo "<br>Not connected";
        $this->READ = $this->load->database('slave02', TRUE);
    }else{
        echo "<br>Connected slave01 : ".$this->READ->conn_id;
    }

    echo "<br>Connected slave02 : ".$this->READ->conn_id;
```

But connection id not print! how can i resolved?

Comment: Worth question actually!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to know the response to the intialize, I’d recommend turning off **auto initialize** to `FALSE` of both the db connections.

```
$db['slave01']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
// AND
$db['slave02']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
```

Then in your code that checks the db state, check TRUE/FALSE of the **`initialize()`** function:

```
$db_obj = $this->load->database('slave01',TRUE);
$connected = $db_obj->initialize();
if (!$connected) 
{
    $db_obj = $this->load->database('slave02',TRUE);
}

$db_obj->conn_id = ($db_obj->pconnect == FALSE) ? $db_obj->db_connect() : $db_obj->db_pconnect();
echo $db_obj->conn_id;
```

Comment: after following condition I'm try to print         echo "<br>Connected : ".$db_obj->conn_id;    than output not comes?

Comment: This is valid in codegniter version 2, as they remove it in version 3, check the link of changelog :
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html?highlight=autoinit